# Is being deficient in vitamin D a possible cause or factor for muscle tension?

Tags: muscle

http://www.naturallivingideas.com/banish-muscle-tension/ :

> It has been found that people who suffer from excessive muscle tension, spasms and pain may be deficient in vitamin D.

Why would being deficient in vitamin D be a possible cause or factor for muscle tension? Alternatively, has any scientific study confirm that claim?

I am mostly interested in forearm muscles. My goal in preventing muscles tightness is to avoid perturbing the tendons that attach to the epicondyles at the elbow end of the humerus.